# How can I store a value (string) in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to store the value of something on my web page for later use by
some javascript functions. I thought of doing something like this where I have
a div with an id of CategoryID and then put the value in that as HTML.

```
   <div id="CategoryID"></div>

   $('#categories > li > a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#CategoryID').html = $(this).attr('data-value')
      refreshGrid('Reference');
   });
```

Then later inside functions such as refreshGrid (and some other functions), I could get the value like this:

```
   var categoryID = $('#CategoryID').val();
```

Does this seem like a good way to store a temporary variable? How about with 
HTML5, is there some way to store values without having to put them inside a 
div or something like that. All I need is to have a value that is stored in some
way on the page.

One more question. If I store the value is this the correct way to do it:

```
$('#CategoryID').html = $(this).attr('data-value')
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use `HiddenField` for storing variable using `jquery` just like this:

```
var tempvalue= $(this).attr('data-value');

$('#my-hidden-field').val(tempvalue);
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use hidden fields on your web-page. For instance.

```
<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="customerId" VALUE="1234567">
```

And then use `.val` in JQuery to work with these values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sometimes using hidden inputs for this purpose depending on the specific case.

```
<input type="hidden" name="CategoryID" id="CategoryID" />
```

Then retrieve it just like this:

```
var categoryID = $('#CategoryID').val();
```

I use inputs since i feel html which isn't markup for the page shouldn't be there.

Sometimes the easiest thing is to just output the variable from the server into script.

Example with ASP.NET:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--

var categoryID = <%= <output value from server goes here> %>;

//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `val()` gets the value of an element. But only inputs have values, therefore you should use a hidden input to store the data:

```
<input id="CategoryId" type="hidden" />
```

But generelly you can access any attribute as described below. Just be aware that `attr()` is old and the new function name is `prop()` -> see Comment for correct explanation regarding `attr()` and `prop()`

Comment: `.attr()` is still correct if you actually are getting/setting attributes rather than properties. It's also the suggested way to retrieve an html5 `data-` attribute if you want to do so without the automatic type-conversion built into the `.data()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the localStorage API introduced in HTML5 if you're keen on that otherwise storing it in hidden fields are the way to go.

```
var idForStorage = $('#CategoryID').val();
window.localStorage.setItem('keyToId', idForStorage);
```

and to fetch it from localStorage

```
var fetchedId = window.localStorage.getItem('keyToId');
```

Note: the localstorage only stores values as Strings, remember that! :)

Also, if you want to be older browser compliant, don't forget to check if localStorage exists and implement a different solution.

Something along the lines of

```
if(typeof(window.localStorage) !== 'undefined'){
    //set item or do whatever
} else {
    //implement other solution or throw an exception
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought but have you considered storing the value in a javascript variable? If you are only using it in javascript why bother putting it in a hidden field or an element at all?

Just declare you variable in the global scope if your not using namespacing/modules but if you are you can store it in the scope of the module that uses it.

Only considerations with this approach is the variable will be reset on page refresh but if you arnt using the value on the server, just in script then that should be ok.

In general I'd only use a hidden input if the server needed to be able to read it.

**EDIT**

In reposone to the comments, if you are using your javascript sensibly which includes the use of namespaceing then this approach works with a certain amount of elegance over cluttering up your markup with "variable holders"

A very quick scaffold for namespacing.....

in a file called MyProject.Global.js

```
//This function is truly global
function namespace(namespaceString) {
   var parts = namespaceString.split('.'),
        parent = window,
        currentPart = '';

   for (var i = 0, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) {
      currentPart = parts[i];
      parent[currentPart] = parent[currentPart] || {};
      parent = parent[currentPart];
   }

   return parent;
}
```

in a file called MyProject.MyPage.Ui.js

```
namespace('MyProject.MyPage');

MyProject.MyPage.Ui = function () {

   var self = this;
   self.settings = {};

   function init(options) {
      $.extend(self.settings, options);
        //any init code goes here, eg bind elements
        setValue();
      };
   };

   //this is considered a "private" function
   function setValue(){

       $('#categories > li > a').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          self.settings.myValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
          refreshGrid('Reference');
       });
   }

   function getValue(){
     return self.settings.myValue;
   }

   //any function within this return are considered "public"
   return {
      init: init,
      getValue: getValue
   };
};
```

finally in your page...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ui = new MyProject.MyPage.Ui();
    ui.init();
}
```

then at any point you can get hold of your value using...

```
MyProject.MyPage.getValue()
```

Comment: Global variables are evil. Encouraging their use encourages my downvote.

Comment: Just a comment but shouldn't you avoid using global vars due to javascripts hoisting?

Comment: whoah guys, read the "if your not using namespacing/modules but if you are you can store it in the scope of the module that uses it." I'll edit to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to store the values as you wish:

- Cookies: the good old way. It is supported everywhere but is more suited for values that need to be kept over different pages and it has other limits (such as size, number of entries, etc).
- SessionStorage: not supported everywhere, but there are shims. It allows you to store a value that will last for a session only. Example:

  `sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`

  `sessionStorage.getItem('key', 'value')`

This accepts strings only as keys and values. If you want to store objects, you can use `JSON.stringify` to store them, and retrieve them later with `JSON.parse`.

- LocalStorage: the brother of sessionStorage, but it has no time limit. It allows you to store datas with the same API as sessionStorage and it's kept over time.

Answer (score 0):

> One more question. If I store the value is this the correct way to do it:

The easier way to use `Data-` attributes with jQuery is to use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
<body id="CategoryData" data-value1="someone" data-value2="sometwo">

....

alert( $("#CategoryData").data('value1') ); // popup with text: someone
alert( $("#CategoryData").data('value2') ); // popup with text: sometwo
```

Personally, I would rather store all the data associated with items in a wrapper `Div` or other elements and use jquery.data.

```
<table data-locationid="1">
  <tr data-personid="1">
    <td>Jon</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-personid="2">
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> HTML5 data-* Attributes
>
> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5 specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the value in one part of your JavaScript for access from another part I'd just use a variable:

```
var categoryID = null;  // set some kind of default

$('#categories > li > a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  categoryID = $(this).attr('data-value');
  refreshGrid('Reference');
});
```

Then later when you need the value just access `categoryID` directly.

***One more question. If I store the value is this the correct way to do it***

If you did want to set the value as the content of your div element you'd use jQuery's `.html()` method or the non-jQuery `.innerHTML` property:

```
$('#CategoryID').html( $(this).attr('data-value') );
// or
$("#CategoryID")[0].innerHTML = $(this).attr('data-value');
```

But if you don't want to use a variable you'd be better off using a hidden input as mentioned in other answers rather than a div.

Answer (score 0):

For browser compatibility, its wiser to use hidden field as suggested by others. But for exploratory reasons, if you would like to use HTML5 it offers WebStorage. For more information please look at http://sixrevisions.com/html/introduction-web-storage/

Also, there is a framework called [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) the offers solution for html5 mobile apps that need a lightweight, adaptive, simple and elegant persistence solution.